# Is AngularJS's ngSanitize supposed to fix tags?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sanitize

Still not sure when to use Sanitize and when not to.  I moved an old database to a new machine. It's got quite a few blog posts.  I used to display these w/ PHP which was horribly intuitive.  I can't say as much for the Angular way.

```
angular.module( 'myApp', ['ngSanitize'] );
function blogController($scope,$http,$sanitize) {

    var site = "http://onfilm.us/gamengai";
    var page = "/fft.php";

    console.log( site + page );

    $http.get( site + page )
    .success(function(response) {

        for ( var i = 0; i < response.length; i++ ) {
            response[i].text = response[i].text.replace( /<br\s*\/?>/mg, "\n" );
            // response[i].text = $sanitize( response[i].text ); // this mangles it
        }

        $scope.data = response;
    });
}
```

I ran a regex on 
 to handle that.

The above gets the data from a PHP script.  If I sanitize the text, it turns those quotes & apostrophe's into garbage. (Maybe b/c they're escaped?)  More importantly though,  is not respected.  It's printed out as a string literal.

I asked this question and was recommended sanitize, but it only solved part of the problem.

EDIT: The original text (in a DB) would be something like '[MyLink](http://example.com/)'.  And that's exactly how it displays on the page.　See it in action here:  http://onfilm.us/gamengai/index.html

Comment: Can you show us what (a) the original text is and (b) what $sanitize is generating?

Comment: Also, on further consideration, what is it that you're expecting $sanitize to do? It strips potentially unsafe html from a string.

Comment: Edited post - have a gander.  I guess I thought sanitize handle tags as well as quotes, apostrophe's, etc.  Is there perhaps another way to prevent Angular from doing whatever it's doing to the tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$sanitize is actually not doing anything untoward with your original string as far as I can tell. Its purpose is to strip potentially unsafe html from a string from an untrusted source; it's working, it's just not what you thought it was.

Your problem is actually unrelated. The issue is how you're binding the text to its element. Currently you are just binding a string, so that's what you're getting. What you actually want is `ng-bind-html`. Now, it does get a little more complicated than that, because to bind html you're going to need to use $sce to first mark the imported resource as trustworthy.

First include $sce as a dependency, then...

```
$http.get(site + page).success(function(response) {

    $scope.data = response.map(function(article) {
        article.text = $sce.trustAsHtml(article.text);
        return article;
    });

});
```

Then in your html, where you currently have this...

```
<div class="text">{{ item.text }}<br></div>
```

change it to:

```
<div class="text" ng-bind-html="item.text"></div>
```

Comment: Addendum: I just noticed you're using an older version of Angular. I'm not sure $sce was available yet in that version, as html binding was handled differently in some earlier versions. In any case I strongly recommend upgrading to Angular 1.3, which has a lot of important bug fixes / general improvements.

Comment: Thanks man -- I will check on this tomorrow.  Shutting it down for tonight.  Looks like good stuff though. One question: how does ng-bind-html="item"> work?  I need it to output a specific member of item... specifically "text".

Comment: Oh, you're correct; that was just a typo. I'll fix it.

Comment: Yowza!  It worked - thanks so much. ;)  Now on to routeParams. :)